# How can I get Date From DateField In ExtJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, extjs4.1

How can I get only date like **02/8/2013 mm/dd/yyyy** from datefield in extjs 4.0 supported on all browser.

my code is as follows

```
   items: [{                  
                xtype: 'datefield',
                fieldLabel: 'Date',
                format: 'm/d/Y',
                altFormats: 'm/d/Y',

            },
```

and i am getting a value from this field like this

```
date = Ext.getCmp('configuration-section-contact-form-date-of-issue').getValue();
```

by using above line i get complete UTC time but I want only date like 02/8/2013.how can i get please help me.
thanks..

Comment: Do not configure [`altFormats`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date-cfg-altFormats).  It defaults to: `m/d/Y|n/j/Y|n/j/y|m/j/y|n/d/y|m/j/Y|n/d/Y|m-d-y|m-d-Y|m/d|m-d|md|mdy|mdY|d|Y-m-d|n-j|n/j`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
dateField.getSubmitValue();
```

See live example on [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zywAe/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Ext.getCmp('configuration-section-contact-form-date-of-issue').getValue().format('m/d/Y');
```

Comment: TypeError: Ext.getCmp(...).getValue(...).format is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Ext.util.Format.Date" method to format the date in desired format.

```
Ext.util.Format.Date(Ext.getCmp('configuration-section-contact-form-date-of-issue').getValue(),'m/d/Y')
```

Comment: TypeError: Ext.util.Format.Date is not a function this is the error

Comment: Please use Ext.util.Format.date instead of Ext.util.Format.Date.

Comment: @sushantjain This is a bad idea. If you change the format in datefild, it will have to change and for Ext.util.Format.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today, I used that way and it worked:

```
var searchText = Ext.util.Format.date(Ext.getCmp('pes1').getValue(), 'd/m/Y');
```